# Force covariance for Scala abstract type with @uncheckedVariance

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

Topics of variance are well presented in many place but unfortunately i do not find any place dealing about this topic with abstract types.

Then in an attempt to understand collection i've written following content

```
trait CollectionOps[+A, +C] {
  this: C =>

  type CC[B] <: BasicColl[B] // Invariant position

  def filter(f: A => Boolean): C

  def map[B](f: A => B): CC[B] // CC is in a covariant position but declared invariant via abstract type 
}

trait BasicColl[+A] extends CollectionOps[A, BasicColl[A]] {
  type CC[B] = BasicColl[B] // this is the problem, the equality
  // But if i let inequality: type CC[B] <: BasicColl[B] 
}

// Do not compile due to previous equality and invariance on CC
trait BasicColl2[+A] extends BasicColl[A] with CollectionOps[A, BasicColl2[A]] {
  type CC[B] = BasicColl2[B]
  // But if i let the previous inequality i can writte type CC[B] <: BasicColl2[B] 
}

trait Test_With_Abstract_Type_Equality {

  // Only BasicColl extist
  def coll1: BasicColl[Int]
  // We have exact type due to equality of CC with BasicColl
  def mapped: BasicColl[Double] = coll1.map(_.toDouble)

  // But no specialized inhéritence possible

}
trait Test_With_Abstract_Type_Inequality {

  def coll1: BasicColl[Int]
  // We have abstract type due to inequality of CC with BasicColl
  def mappedWithAbstractTypeDef: BasicColl[Int]#CC[Double] = coll1.map(_.toDouble)

  // BasicColl2 can exist
  def coll2: BasicColl2[Int]
  // We have abstract type due to inequality of CC with BasicColl2
  def mappedWithAbstractTypeDef2: BasicColl2[Int]#CC[Double] = coll2.map(_.toDouble)

}
```

Scala pattern do not use astract type but directly a covariant paremetrized type CC as follow

```
trait IterableOnceOps[+A, +CC[_], +C]
```

Covariance has the advantage to facilitating trait mixing.

But using a Higher Kind of this type at type parameter level prevent any extension to class with more than 1 parametrized type where using abstract type allow extension to more complex class at the cost of having abstract type as output.
Here the point i tried that but i m not confident enough about risk of it.

```
// Redefinition
trait CollectionOps[+A, +C] {
  this: C =>

  type CC[B] <: BasicColl[B] // Invariant position

  def filter(f: A => Boolean): C

  def map[B](f: A => B): CC[B] // but CC is in a covariant position 
}
// Redefinition
trait BasicColl[+A] extends CollectionOps[A, BasicColl[A]]


trait CollectionOpsLocked1[+A, +CCC[B] <: BasicColl[B], +C] extends CollectionOps[A, C] {
  this: C =>

  type CC[B] = CCC[B] @uncheckedVariance // this is my question

  // If i use CC ONLY in covariant position is there any risk ?

}

trait BasicColl2[+A] extends BasicColl[A] with CollectionOpsLocked1[A, BasicColl2, BasicColl2[A]]
trait BasicColl3[+A] extends BasicColl2[A] with CollectionOpsLocked1[A, BasicColl3, BasicColl3[A]]

trait Test {

  def coll1: BasicColl[Int]
  def mappedWithAbstractTypeDef: BasicColl[Int]#CC[Double] = coll1.map(_.toDouble)

  // BasicColl2 can exist
  def coll2: BasicColl2[Int]
  def mapped2: BasicColl2[Double] = coll2.map(_.toDouble)

  // BasicColl3 can exist
  def coll3: BasicColl3[Int]
  def mapped3: BasicColl3[Double] = coll3.map(_.toDouble)

}
```

More generaly is there any risk to use `@uncheckedVariance` to some place where covariance/contravariance are legit ?

Comment: "But using a Higher Kind of this type at type parameter level prevent any extension to class with more than 1 parametrized type where using abstract type allow extension to more complex class at the cost of having abstract type as output." - this isn't exactly true. Your `CC[_]` expects exactly one type parameter. Your return type applies exactly one parameter. Even if you extend your class Liskov Substitution Principle applies, so your extension will also have to expect and apply exactly one parameter.

Comment: And if you wanted to use something with 2 params and have one of them fixed by yourself... then this is equal to using kind projector. So the expression power is kinda the same.